# Gives me "Nothing Here" when I try to choose Device for Android Studio

Tags: android

As you can see in the pic I cant choose a device and gives me rendering error

This is what happens:

[image]

Comment: As the error suggests 'no render target selected' try picking a android target (right top android button in your screenshot, which is currently <null>)

Comment: Use the SDK manager to update your build tools and sdks. Make sure that you preview your layout with a target of 4.x and above. This may have been fixed already, but I recall the layout designer used to have trouble rendering things if the chosen target sdk wasn't one of the latest ones.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use a hardware device or an AVD ?

Anyway, the problem may come from different options :

- Is the SDK well setup for Android Studio ?
- Have you configured an AVD ?
- Have you restarted Android Studio ?
- Have you installed the usb drivers from the SDK ?